# How can I publish my Android app with zero permissions when exporting from AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

In my application XML I have this descriptor:

```
<![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
</manifest>]]>
```

But I can't seem to get rid of the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission. I tried removing that and making it just:

`<uses-permission />`

But when it installs it still asks for internet permission.

Does anyone know how to remove all permissions?

Comment: Does your application make any requests? If so - that's why it's needed. Otherwise, it's never said it's mandatory..

Comment: In addition to what Andrey said, delete the entire line. Don't just delete the `android:name` attribute.

Comment: iirc, you ALWAYS need the internet permission if you publish a debug apk. this is needed for the communication between your console and the app (for traces etc.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm not accessing the internet, but I will be using in-app purchases, so maybe it's just best to leave it in?

Comment: You **must** have the `INTERNET` permission to use in-app purchases. "The android.permission.INTERNET and com.android.vending.BILLING permissions must be present for In-App Billing to work." See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-billing-ane.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_11